# Delete a Node in the Middle of a linked list, Given only access to that Node. - Python

Tags: python

I am trying delete the middle node, but when I call the function and try to get hold of second node after the given node, it appears to be None. Below is my code, please help me correct it.

```
class Node:
    # Constructor to initialize the node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data= data
        self.next= None

class LinkedList():

    # Function to initialize head
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    # Function to insert a new node at the beginning
    def insert(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        node.next=self.head
        self.head = node

    # Function to print elements of the linked list    
    def printlist(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            print current.data 
            current = current.next

    def deleteMiddle(self, node):
        second = node.next
        print second.data
        if node is None:
            return
        node.data = second.data
        node.next = second.next

llist = LinkedList()
llist.insert(10)
llist.insert(15)
mid = Node(20)
llist.insert(mid.data)
llist.insert(16)
llist.insert(17)
llist.insert(19)
print "Before deleting middle or any node"
llist.printlist()
print "After deleting middle or any node"
llist.deleteMiddle(mid)
llist.printlist()
```

**Update 1**: I have added below changes, and it is working fine. But want to know, if it is correct and can be (insert and addNode function) combined into one function. Also I want to understand better way to write this code, as there can be a case, where I want to delete any node and will have access to that node only. With my code, I am defining node and then deleting it, but I still feel there should be better approach than my code.

```
def addNode(self, node):
        node.next =  self.head
        self.head = node

llist.addNode(mid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat, it looks like you are adding the data from your middle node `mid`, rather than the node itself into the head position. When you try to delete `mid`, you need to find the node in the linked list that looks like `mid` since it is not the exact same node.

Alternatively, you can choose to add your `Node` called `mid`, by creating a new insert function that takes a `Node` instead of `data`.

i.e., `def insert(self, node):`

Comment: I am new data structures, so I implemented Update 1 and it is working fine. Please check Update 1 and let me know, if that is correct approach. Also Please let me know, if I can modify insert and addNode function into one.

Comment: That looks fine. Right now your add node function puts the node at the head. I recommend writing a function to traverse the list to a given point (imagine finding the 3rd node in the list). Once you figure that out, you will be able to write code to insert a node at any location of the linked list.

Consider also drawing a picture of what your code does. I always found visualizations particularly helpful when coding up a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You did not actually insert your `mid` node into the linked list; instead, you inserted a brand new node into the list with the same data value.  Nothing you do via `mid` will have any effect on your list, as it has no connection to the list.